# How to run multiple instances of a form class simultaneously in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, forms, asynchronous

I've written a form class that runs stand alone and closes itself upon a keystroke.  I want to be able to run multiple instances of this form class at the same time and can't figure out how to do so.  Most of the examples involving threading involve using 'addressof' pointing to a specific routine, but I want to run multiple instances of the entire form class asynchronously.

The form that runs a screensaver is called 'frmMain' and it operates on a monitor as defined by the public variable "MonitorNumber".  Running the code below works fine on whichever monitor I define, and then the form instance closes itself when someone moves the mouse (as it should).

```
 SSInst = New frmMain
 SSInst.MonitorNumber = 0
 SSInst.ShowDialog()
 SSInst.Dispose()
```

Very simply, here is what I WANT to do though:

```
 SSInst = New frmMain
 SSInst2 = New frmMain
 SSInst.MonitorNumber = 0
 SSInst2.MonitorNumber = 1
 SSInst.ShowDialog()
 SSInst2.ShowDialog()

 SSInst.Dispose()
 SSInst2.Dispose()
```

If I was able to run this, I'm sure it would work as an instance of frmMain is self contained, but of course I can't run it because the code would stop after SSInst.ShowDialog until that form instance closes.

How can I run both instances at the same time???

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I assume the form handles all the required stuff for closing and what not, the following should work for you:

```
SSInst = New frmMain
SSInst2 = New frmMain
SSInst.MonitorNumber = 0
SSInst2.MonitorNumber = 1
SSInst.Show()
SSInst2.Show()

application.DoEvents
Do While ssInst.Visible AndAlso ssInst2.Visible
    Application.DoEvents
Loop

SSInst.Dispose()
SSInst2.Dispose()
```

Comment: Well, neither one of these responses would work for the reasons alluded to in my original request.  The first one requires the address of a specific subroutine, and I want to run the form asynchronously - not a specific subroutine.  If I run an instance of the form, it will run the load, activate, etc. events correctly and also close itself when done.

Comment: ...and the 2nd example doesn't address the problem at all as the whole block of code provided would never run until the forms are closed.  The problem is that once the first instance is "shown", the code to "show" the 2nd instance will not run until the first instance closes itself; much less the block of code provided, which would not run until that 2nd instance closes itself.

Comment: Why wouldn't it run? It is NOT using `ShowDialog`, it is using `Show`. Then it stays in the loop until one of the 2 are no longer visible.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf sub1)
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf sub2)
```